# How to fix "'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'string_types'" error in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am watching [this](https://youtu.be/NM8Ue4znLP8?t=219) tutorial where I am trying to use [iexfinance](https://addisonlynch.github.io/iexfinance/stable/configuration.html#output-formatting) to get stock data. You have the option to choose the data type when requesting the data, I chose "pandas". When I run the built-in function I get an error that reads `AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'string_types'`

I am using python 3.7. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both iexfinance and pandas. I also created and IEX cloud account and passed in a secret key like the documentation states, but the same error. The tutorial doesn't mention any of these steps and its confusing why his works and mine isn't.

I have tried to make the code simpler by following examples on the website: Even when running:

```
from iexfinance.stocks import Stock

df = Stock("AAPL", output_format="pandas")

print(df.get_quote().head())
```

The error persists

The expected output is:

```
                      AAPL
avgTotalVolume    30578248
calculationPrice     close
change               -0.58
changePercent     -0.00298
close               207.27
```

The output I am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = Stock("AAPL", output_format="pandas")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/iexfinance/stocks/base.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.symbols = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), _handle_lists(symbols)))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/iexfinance/utils/__init__.py", line 43, in _handle_lists
    if isinstance(l, (compat.string_types, int)):
AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'string_types'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try reverting the pandas version to 0.24.2 as a workaround:

`pip install pandas==0.24.2`

At this point I am still not sure if a bug in pandas or something else.

EDIT: Probably the iexfinance is using some internals in Pandas, and pandas has undergone a major change dropping python 2 and all the compatibility code.

This is also already on their issue tracker:
https://github.com/addisonlynch/iexfinance/issues/163

Comment: Wow, that seemed to work. Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The method about: 
    pip install pandas==0.24.2
is right~ try this.

Answer (score 0):

To date **2 October 2019**, just update iexfinance to the latest version (0.4.3) and the problem is solved. 
Do this:

```
pip install iexfinance --upgrade
```