# Fixing "AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'string_types'" error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyterhub

I am trying to run the [tsfresh](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html) package on Jupyterhub Python3. While running the quickstart code for extracting the features, I am getting the  following error "AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'string_types'.

I tried downgrading pandas version to 0.24.2 as mentioned in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334052/how-to-fix-pandas-compat-has-no-attribute-string-types-error-in-python3). But it doesn't downgrade for me. It remains at 0.25.2 when I check the version using `pd.__version__`

Comment: welcome to SO.  you should include as much code as possible in order to reproduce your problem and show what you have tried.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out, you may consider closing this question, and reposting a question specifically on getting pandas to downgrade in your environment. Seems that is the crux of this issue here, not the attribute error.